# Project No Longer Functional in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I originally imported the Adobe Marketing Cloud (Omniture) v3x into my project, then changed my mind and replaced it with v4. I ran into problems with v4 though, and decided to remove it and go back to the original v3 library. When I tested it last night, it was working fine and sending hits like I expected. This morning I fired it up, and the project no longer works at all. It tries to start up, seems to fail at remotely loading assets (never a problem before), and eventually crashes without giving me a meaningful exception. All I get are screens and screens of stuff like this:

```
08-20 12:17:05.018  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT unchain all for threadid=1
08-20 12:17:05.769  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=32: spin on suspend #1 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=32: spin on suspend #2 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ "downloader" prio=5 tid=32 RUNNABLE
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x43195640 self=0x61f07738
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=31777 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1643150224
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=1 core=0
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:208)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:161)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:246)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:186)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:375)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:328)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:196)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
08-20 12:17:06.519  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.tilesource.WebSourceTileLayer.getBitmapFromURL(WebSourceTileLayer.java:174)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.tilesource.WebSourceTileLayer.getDrawableFromTile(WebSourceTileLayer.java:120)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.tilesource.WebSourceTileLayer.getDrawableFromTile(WebSourceTileLayer.java:28)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader$TileLoader.loadTile(MapTileDownloader.java:154)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleLayerBase$TileLoader.run(MapTileModuleLayerBase.java:316)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-20 12:17:06.529  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-20 12:17:06.549  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-20 12:17:06.569  31576-31777/com.newspress.hurricanehub I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 08-20 12:17:06.569 31576:31777 I/dalvikvm ]
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE JIT
```

I could post my full log if that would helpful, but there's a LOT of that. I've tried everything I know. I took the module out of the project and put it back in, I tried deleting my gradle and iml files and reimporting, I even reset the project to a previous commit from before I changed any libraries or had done anything that would hurt the project. Same result, it's just completely broken now, won't load anything, and eventually crashes. Any insight? I don't really know where to look or what to try at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was mistaken in assuming something I had changed in the code was causing the issue. Once I realized older apks were also broken, further testing revealed the data stream for the map was trying to load so many polygons it was crashing the Linux kernel. Once I removed the polygons from the map, everything worked fine. If something breaks I just always figure I probably broke it, but that isn't always a safe assumption!